# Error 400 when trying to reset user password on Red Hat SSO 7.3 (Keycloak) with Java API

Tags: java, openshift, keycloak, redhat, redhat-sso

I'm trying to create a user with a temporary password on Red Hat Single Sign On 7.3 (Keycloak behind the scene) through Java API.

Locally (with standard Keycloak, jboss/keycloak:9.0.0 Docker image), it is working fine.
But when deploying the same on Openshift 4.4 project, I get a 400 error from Red Hat SSO (7.3).
Unfortunately, I have not so much in the log and I don't have possibility to configure anything on the Red Hat SSO server for it to be more verbose.

On the Red Hat SSO server, a dedicated "keycloak-admin" client has been created in the application Realm.
Client is enabled with only "Service Accounts Enabled" option to ON.
In "Service Account Roles", all roles from "realm-management" have been assigned and are effective.

I'm using this Maven dependency to deal with Keycloak Java API:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
   <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
   <version>9.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is how I create connection with Keycloak through Java code:

```
Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
            .serverUrl(keycloakProperties.getHost())
            .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
            .realm("app_realm")
            .clientId("keycloak-admin")
            .clientSecret(xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx)
            .resteasyClient(
                new ResteasyClientBuilder()
                    .connectionPoolSize(10).build()
            ).build();
keycloak.tokenManager().getAccessToken();
RealmResource realmResource = keycloak.realm("app_realm");
```

Client secret set is matching with secret in the "keycloak-admin" client in "Credentials" part.

Here is how I create user through Java code :

```
final UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
user.setEnabled(true);
user.setEmailVerified(true);
user.setUsername(username);
user.setFirstName(firstName);
user.setLastName(lastName);
user.setEmail(email);

try {
   final Response response = realmResource.users().create(user);
   final String userId = CreatedResponseUtil.getCreatedId(response);
} catch (final Exception exception) {
   log.error("Exception when createKeycloakUser",exception);
}
```

**This part is working fine locally and also in Red Hat SSO. User is created and can be retrieved on Keycloak.**

Then I try to reset password like this:

```
final UserResource userResource = realmResource.users().get(userId );

final CredentialRepresentation passwordCred = new CredentialRepresentation();
passwordCred.setTemporary(true);
passwordCred.setType(CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD);
passwordCred.setValue(generateRandomPassword());
userResource.resetPassword(passwordCred);
```

*generateRandomPassword* is a method generating a random password which matches with password policies defined on local Keycloak and on Red Hat SSO (Authentication/Password Policy).

This last part of the code is working fine locally but I get the 400 error on Red Hat SSO.

For you to know, I also try to create user with password directly but behavior is exactly the same.
I also make a try with a connection to Keycloak using "admin-cli" client and admin account but issue remains.

Thanks in advance for all help or advices you could provide ! I'm stuck on that and have no more idea for now...

Comment: Can you check the server logs for details of the 400 error?

Comment: Hello, unfortunately I don't see anything related to this error in the logs for Red Hat SSO pod on Openshift. And on my application pod, just get a 400 Bad Request error with nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. It was just because the password was null. Maybe you should check the return of generateRandomPassword(). I hope this will help you if you still have this problem